# How To Find All Code References To a Particular Assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Does anyone know if there is any way to find all code references to a referenced assembly?

For example, lets say there is a project with 15 assembly references and not all of them are being used. Would it be possible to see all usages of one particular reference?

The only way I know how to do this is to delete the reference and try and build. The error list shows me all the references but this seems kind of hacky..

I am using VS 2012, Update 1.

thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if it's ReSharper's functionality or it's built in, but on my system I can right-click a referenced assembly, and get a context menu from which I can find all references of this assembly in the given project.

Comment: Maybe its ReSharper.. i don't seem to have that option.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Updated to show VS version.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight In VS2012 Professional, without ReSharper, when I right-click, the menu says only "View in Object Browser", "Remove", and "Properties".

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I have the same options as well.

Comment: If you right-click on an assembly under References and see a 'Find Code Dependent on Module', then this is ReSharper functionality

Comment: Also see [Tools for finding unused references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142627/) and the threads linked to that question page.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is remove unused references, the C# compiler does that automatically.  To see what was omitted, just open the compiled assembly in ILSpy and compare the references their with the ones in the project.